# what does less power costs parameter mean?

Tags: mining-profitability, terminology

I see Less power costs everywhere, what is the difference between Less Power Costs vs. 24h Power Cost ? 
http://www.bitcoinx.com/profit/

Answer (score 1):

"24h power cost" is how much the power your miner uses in 24 hours costs you. "Less power costs" is the value of the coins mined minus the cost of the power to mine them.